# Is Sharepoint retrun ID in response when I Insert Items In List using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am Insert Data in Sharepoint list using **REST API.**

Its inserted Successfully but I want in Response that inserted Record **ID**.

Is there any way to get it.?

I don't want to call request again.

Any Help greatly Appreciated.

Comment: You could do a Caml-Query with rowlimit 1 and sort by id descending. The result is the last created element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are creating Item using REST API it will give you a JSON response in returned. If you parse your JSON using [JSON Parser](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) you can see all the details regarding created item is visible. So you can parse JSON response and get whatever you want. See attached snap.

[image]

Comment: Dear when i am  call POST request using REST Its not return any json. Is there any header for it i have to set?

Comment: I tried this practically and then posted the snap. Still I will be checking once again for your query.

Comment: actually i am fire Request from Mobile application.

Comment: Ok. I can't verify that, I can only verify with Client Machine and I am getting it. Because I am not having mobile development environment

Comment: can you give me which header you pass in post request?

Comment: Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose"; and ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";

Answer (score 2):

Yes It returns a `ID` and also `Id` in the response. You can access like

```
yourResponse.d.ID
// OR
yourResponse.d.Id
```

`yourResponse.d` is the item you have just inserted.

`ID` and `Id` both are the same thing.